# How Flash Bios Nokia booklet 3g

Tags: boot, usb, bios, flash

I would like to know how to flash a bios mod that have extension .rom
This guys, of ["bios mod forum"](https://www.bios-mods.com/forum/Thread-Nokia-Booklet-3G-Phoenix-SecureCore-Post-26?page=3) made this modded bios
Link to download the modded bios: [here](https://www.bios-mods.com/forum/attachment.php?aid=8639)

I searched but nobody says how to flash a .rom bios. My USB is FAT32 formatted, 8GB.

I tried to put the file in the USB and boot from the USB, but it says:

> System found not found

I have no OS installed in the HDD.

How to flash using .rom BIOS?

Comment: You wish to flash a modified BIOS? Depending on the security functions of this system that may not be possible. Do not ask us to visit links to understand your problem, but include all necessary information in the question you post. Use the EDIT button to clarify your question.

Comment: Sorry, the link was only for more clarity, basically I just want to know how flash it...

Comment: Dis you follow the basic instructions for flashing the BIOS via bootable media for the system? As in, most systems have a function for flashing bios firmware from outside the OS as a recovery method. So, have you looked up how to do that? Have you checked to make sure the system is set to boot to USB?